# How can I override requests' randomly generated multipart boundary in Python?

Tags: python, python-requests, multipart, boundary

Example:

```
with open('foobar.txt') as f:
    r = requests.post("http://requestb.in/179gbs61", files={'file':f})
```

This produces a request with a different a multipart boundary every time. i.e., this call produces a different request every time.

For the purposes of testing, I would like to fix to some value like `I_AM_NOT_A_MULTIPART_BOUNDARY` or some such.

Q: How can I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import requests.packages.urllib3 as urllib3
urllib3.filepost.choose_boundary = lambda: 'I_AM_NOT_A_MULTIPART_BOUNDARY'

with open('foobar.txt') as f:
    r = requests.post("http://requestb.in/179gbs61", files={'file':f})
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Does exactly what I want.